# Upload multiple files with multiple form field using Django?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have write down a View and template to upload two files with two different form field, but unfortunately its upload only one file which is coming from the first input file.

This is template file which should upload two files into media folder:
tamplate.html

```
{% extends 'protocol/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}


{% block content %}

<style type="text/css">

.button {
    background-color:  #ff9800; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.input {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.text {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.heading{
    margin-left: 250px;
}
</style>

 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="heading">
 <h1> Machine Learning Modeling.. </h1>
 <h2> Upload CSV files contains both, positive and Negative peptides.. </h2>
 </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="input" type="file" name="myfile">
    <input class="input" type="file" name="myfile_1">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  {% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p class="text" >File uploaded successfully. </p>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings

import os
import glob
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
#from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
import urllib, mimetypes
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str


# Create your views here.
def predict(request):



    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile_1']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile_1']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)


        return render(request, 'prediction/thanks.html', {})

    return render(request, 'prediction/prediction.html')
```

How can I upload multiple files with multiple input field of a form

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `.get` method on your `request.FILES`.
In the code provided below, I have also renamed your `myfile` variables so they are unique... just as a good practice.

```
# Posted form.
if request.method == "POST":

    if request.FILES.get('myfile', None):
        file_1 = request.FILES.get('myfile')
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(file_1.name, file_1)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

    if request.FILES.get('myfile_1', None):
        file_2 = request.FILES.get('myfile_1')
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(file_2.name, file_2)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
```

Try this suggestion out. If it doesn't work, try printing the output from your form submission and see what is happening.